# How to test your prediction for insurance company dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, test-data

I have a dataset of an insurance company for my data science class project. My ultimate business objective in this project is to sell more policies to existing customers/customer segments.

Firstly, I want to **cluster** my customers through k-mean model with **RFM** scores then use apriori algorithm to find **association rules** among this clusters. Later, I can find which customer/customer segments I can sell more product/s. Yet my teacher **want me to test my prediction** and said that since the **policies are repeated every year**, you can not split your data in terms of last 3 months is test data-set and the rest of the 9 months is train data or etc. To sum up, he wants me to test my prediction in more accurate way. How can i test my prediction in this specific case?

My data set includes **not much** **demografics** info about customers such as age, income, education, or etc. Then I want to use RFM scores since I know the customers' all purchasing records. Columns include what **policy type** they purchase, **when** they purchase, **which company** they purchase with, the **pricing** of the purchase, which **region** they purchase in, **telephone** numbers, **adresses**, **mail** adress etc.

Insurance types are life, car, traffic, residence insurance, fire etc.

Comment: What does your dataset look like? There is not really enough information provided for anyone to be able to suggest a sufficiently more accurate means of testing your prediction.

Comment: Okey thanks for reply, added on the quesiton.